# how to use track_visibility=always and store=true with compute field?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

Here, i need the actual sales at the side of crm opportunity.

I had done all computation part but, not store that value with 
`track_visibility='always'` and `store=True`.

```
from odoo import api,fields,models,_

class CrmLead(models.Model):

    _inherit = "crm.lead"


    actual_sales = fields.Float(string="Actual Sales", store=True, compute="compute_actual_sales", track_visibility='always')

    @api.depends('order_ids')
    def compute_actual_sales(self):
        for record in self:
            total_actual_sales_amount_in_opp = 0
            for order in record.order_ids:
                if order.state == 'sale':
                    sales_amount_in_opp = order.amount_total
                    print">>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<sales_amount_in_opp>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><", sales_amount_in_opp  
                    total_actual_sales_amount_in_opp = order.amount_total + total_actual_sales_amount_in_opp
            print">>>>>>>>>>>>>><<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<total_sales_amount_in_opp>>>>>>>>>>>>>>><", total_actual_sales_amount_in_opp  
        record.actual_sales = total_actual_sales_amount_in_opp
```